# changing the format of variable values

Tags: r, variables, format

I have a situation here and looking for a convenient way to convert/change a variable entries by using one or two line of scripts. This is an example of the data that I have:

```
id <- c("001/15","002/15","003/15")
con <- c("white","green","blue")
entry <- data.frame(id,con)
entry
      id   con
1 001/15 white
2 002/15 green
3 003/15  blue
```

I used these lines to change the id entries to what I would want, but I have a lot more entries:

```
entry$id <- as.character(entry$id)
entry$id[entry$id=="001/15"] <- "00115"
entry$id[entry$id=="002/15"] <- "00215"
entry$id[entry$id=="003/15"] <- "00315"

entry
     id   con
1 00115 white
2 00215 green
3 00315  blue
```

I am looking for a one liner to change the id entries all at once!

Thank you for your help,

baz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `sub`:

```
> sub("/", "", entry$id)
[1] "00115" "00215" "00315"

> entry$id <- sub("/", "", entry$id)
> entry
     id   con
1 00115 white
2 00215 green
3 00315  blue
```

Edit to answer your comment: just use `entry$entry <- rownames(entry)` (if you want to keep that as a character column) or `entry$entry <- seq_along(nrow(entry))` (if you want to keep that as a numeric column). And you can rearrange your columns like:

```
> entry$entry <- seq_along(nrow(entry))
> entry[, c(length(entry), 1:(length(entry) - 1))]
  entry    id   con
1     1 00115 white
2     2 00215 green
3     3 00315  blue
```

Comment: I would like to have my new data frame look like this:                                                                                                             entry
     id   con
1 00115 white
2 00215 green
3 00315  blue

Comment: Just fyi, `rownames(entry)` is a character vector,  You may want to use `seq_len(nrow(entry))` or `as.numeric` to get numeric values for `entry`

Comment: @Richard Scriven, thank you for that point. much appreciated!